# Informatica server upgrade from 901 to 910

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm having informatica 901 server and 910 client installed in my PC. When i was trying to run wf's facing permission issues. After searching in sites and blogs i understood that its not good to have different versions of client and server. Can any one please suggest can i upgrade server from 901 to 910. If any one did it previously please help me with any document or links

```
 error: um_10059 authentication failed because authentication token is invalid
```

Thanks,
 Sai.

Comment: If you have the 910 server software, you can just run it. I guess the installer gives you an option to upgrade the existing version.

Comment: it will give upgrade option that is fine. But am asking for suggetions or any docs

Comment: Successfully upgraded the version with out any issues :)

Comment: hey congrats! you could write a short tutorial as an answer including any special steps you had to do!

Comment: Nothing much samik. Shut down repository,Integration and Node. Stop informatica services. Install the server and give upgrade option..